# Using Dropbox's zxcvbn password strength estimator

Tags: javascript, jquery, dropbox

I'm trying to get [zxcvbn, Dropbox's password strength estimator](http://tech.dropbox.com/?p=165), to work right... but I'm having some issues!

I've included the asynchronous loader.

My next problem is that I don't know enough JS to figure out how to actually use this thing....

```
<input id="password" name="password" size="35" class="textInput required" type="password">
```

is it used as some kind of monitor on that field?

Thanks for the help, I'm still learning JS/jQuery...

Comment: Since you're new to JS, it might be easiest to find a jQuery password meter plugin, and then just configure that plugin to use the global function that zxcvbn creates.

Comment: +1 for the wonderful password strength checker, liked it :)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
<input id="password" name="password" size="35" class="textInput required" type="password"/>
<div id="result">
Laaa laa laa...
</div>
```

---

```
$('#password').keyup(function() {
  var textValue = $(this).val();
  var result = zxcvbn(textValue);
  $('#result').html("cracktime : " + result.crack_time);
  //use this result as you like
    /*
    result.entropy            # bits

result.crack_time         # estimation of actual crack time, in seconds.

result.crack_time_display # same crack time, as a friendlier string:
                          # "instant", "6 minutes", "centuries", etc.

result.score              # [0,1,2,3,4] if crack time is less than
                          # [10**2, 10**4, 10**6, 10**8, Infinity].
                          # (useful for implementing a strength bar.)

result.match_sequence     # the list of patterns that zxcvbn based the
                          # entropy calculation on.

result.calculation_time   # how long it took to calculate an answer,
                          # in milliseconds. usually only a few ms.
    */
});
```

Fiddle for you, http://jsfiddle.net/MhZ4p/

replace the traverse function for just crack time

```
traverse(result);
```

to:

```
$('#result').html("cracktime : " + result.crack_time);
```

Comment: Great! Now... let's say I just want to use result.crack_time, how can I make that display in a div lower in the HTML (how can I use it...haha)?

Comment: Did anyone try this with require.js?