# Javascript regexp character matching

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm looking into using a jQuery password strength indicator and have found one that looks suitable.

It increases the password strength score if special characters are detected:

```
if (password.match(/(.*[!,@,#,$,%,^,&,*,?,_,~].*[!,@,#,$,%,^,&,*,?,_,~])/)){ score += 5 ;}
```

However I'd like to be able to specify additional special characters and because these lists of special characters are used in several places, I'd like to only specify the list once:

```
list = array(!,@,#,$,%,^,&,*,?,_,~,[,],{,},(,));
if (password.match(/(.*[list].*[list])/)){ score += 5 ;}
```

Is this possible?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11596556/using-dropboxs-zxcvbn-password-strength-estimator/11596627#11596627

Comment: Don't see any usage of jQuery here. Of course you can define list somewhere in global. Use list.join("") to get serialized chars list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use strings:

```
var special = "!@#$%^&*?_~[]{}()".split('').join('\\');
if (password.match(new RegExp("(.*[" + special + "].*[" + special + "])")))...
```

(The join-with-backslashes escapes the special characters so they are treated literally by the regex engine.)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, if you use the [RegExp() constructor](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_regexp.asp), you can pass in a string as regexp.

```
var list = ['\\!', '\\@', '\\#', '\\%'];
var reg = new RegExp('(.*['+ list.join(',') + '].*['+ list.join(',') +'])');
if (reg.test("MySuperPassword!#_123")) {
    score += 5;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to separate chars by `,` in regex:

```
var list = "[\\!@#\\$%\\^&\\*\\?_~]";
var your_regex = new RegExp(".*" + list + ".*" + list);
if (your_regex.test(password)){
  score += 5;
}
```

Comment: you should also escape meaningful symbols, such as `?` ... e.g. `/[\?\!]/`

Comment: you also can't embed variables in strings like `"list"` in JS, they need to be concatenated. Sorry, I guess I'm that guy

Comment: @Tim: there's no need to escape `?` or `!` here.

Answer (score 0):

Why would you need a regex?

```
var list  = ['!','@','#','$','%','^','&','*','?','_','~','[',']','{','}','(',')'],
    score = 0;

for (var i=list.length;i--;) {
    if ( password.indexOf(list[i]) ) score++;
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/upNGZ/)